# Passing SQL Server statements into a stored procedure so the stored procedure can execute them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have the following SQL Server stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Create date: April 4 2017
-- Description: This stored procedure deletes a selected row from the table.
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedureTestbench_Delete]
    @TestKey INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  -- NOCOUNT 

    -- This always deletes the last record from the table.
    DELETE FROM StoredProcedureTest
    WHERE TestKey = (SELECT MAX(TestKey) FROM StoredProcedureTest)     
END;
RETURN
```

I execute it using:

```
/*  This routine executes the stored procedure that deletes a selected StoredProcedureTestbench table row  */
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DECLARE @ReturnCode int;

EXECUTE @ReturnCode = dbo.StoredProcedureTestbench_Delete
BEGIN
    SELECT @ReturnCode AS Return_Code
END;
GO
```

Is it possible to pass `'(SELECT MAX(TestKey) FROM StoredProcedureTest)'` to the stored procedure from the procedure that calls the stored procedure as a parameter?

In a more general sense, how can I pass SQL Server statements into a stored procedure so the stored procedure can execute them?

Comment: "Passing SQL Server statements into a stored procedure so the stored procedure can execute them

" - just don't !

Comment: You should avoid assembling SQL from fragments, if at all possible. If you're assembling from fragments, you have to be extremely thorough to avoid any SQL Injection risks.

Comment: It is possible and simple. But... _Alert_ Nobody would suggest you that. Take above comments seriously.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give You the way how to do that, but please read all that comments saying You should not use it seriously and think for a moment if what You are doing is for sure safe.

SQL injection means that You should be 100% sure that sql parameter won't be changed by user for text like "drop database", select all data from all tables and things like that.

If You control that parameter Yourself, like You create that string and You are SURE it is safe, You could do something like that :

sp_executesql will execute Your dynamically created sql.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedureTestbench_Delete] @sqltextparameter varchar(max),
    @TestKey INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   

 declare @executestatement varchar(max)
    set @executestatement = 'DELETE FROM StoredProcedureTest
    WHERE TestKey ='

   exec  sp_executesql @executestatement + @sqltextparameter 
END;
RETURN
```

and later just execute it adding Your text as parameter:

```
/*  This routine executes the stored procedure that deletes a selected StoredProcedureTestbench table row  */
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DECLARE @ReturnCode int;

EXECUTE @ReturnCode = dbo.StoredProcedureTestbench_Delete '(SELECT MAX(TestKey) FROM StoredProcedureTest)'
BEGIN
    SELECT @ReturnCode AS Return_Code
END;
GO
```